# How can i 'complete' my dart SDK rather than installing a separate version when using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I installed flutter by downloading and installing a release version.
It contains a *partial* dart SDK in its cache subfolder. 
Namely, it's missing (amongst others executables) dart2native.

I realize I could just download and install a separate dart SDK from their website, then change all my paths to point to this newer, complete SDK. But that's exactly the problem - I do not wish to run 2 sdk version in parallel, it's confusing and likely will cause errors down the line (for example, my copy of android studio might be pointing at this or that SDK, and god knows what other tools might point towards it).

Question: is there a way to 'fill' my flutter dart SDK with the missing tools? Or am i doomed to run 2 version of dart SDK in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - after much googling, I found a repo maintainer stating that "*For now, if you want to do to Dart development and use the Dart terminal commands (like dartfmt, pub, or dart2native), it's recommended that you download and install the Dart SDK. If you'd like you can also add it to path.*"

This is clearly sub-optimal. In fact just as I expected it seems to have led to a few people having faced issues, comment on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43968 if you'd like to see this addressed.